# IntelliJ can't find LocalDate.of() method

Tags: java, date, intellij-idea

I am doing a program where I need to use this line

```
this.currentDay = new LocalDate.of(tmp.getYear(),tmp.getMonth(),1);
```

InteliJ find the .of and propose me to use it, which is what i want to do, but as soon as i click on it, the of become red and an error bubble say "cannot resolve symbol of"

for context the problematic function is in  this class

```
public class DayOfVacation {
  LocalDate currentDay;
  User user;
  Vacation vacation;

  public DayOfVacation(User user, Vacation vacation){
    LocalDate tmp = LocalDate.now();
    this.currentDay = new LocalDate.of(tmp.getYear(),tmp.getMonth(),1);

  }
}
```

Comment: `LocalDate.of` is already returning an object, there is no need to use the `new` operator (it has already been created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a static [`LocalDate.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of(int,int,int)) method you can't use the `new` operator. Your code should be:

```
this.currentDay = LocalDate.of(tmp.getYear(), tmp.getMonth(), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're doing `new LocalDate.of(`, the only possible interpretation in Java is that you're looking to *instantiate* an inner class called `of` located within `LocalDate`, which has a constructor which takes three parameters. There is no such thing, which is why you get the error that you do.

This is not an inner class. It's a static method. You must remove the `new` keyword.

Comment: This explanation made it very clear! Prepending `new` had become a habit.